# Android ViewPager.ChildCount give me wrong count

Tags: c#, android, android-viewpager, xamarin.android

I just Created ViewPager With PagerAdapter and I put inside it 3 items but when i run the program ViewPager.ChildCount give me 2 ?
and when i scroll to second View the adapter add the third item and give me 3 count but when I scroll to the final View (3) it give me 2 in the count , but at this time the last 2 items !!
in my code I'm Trying to display the position in the textView inside the layout
it give my right numbers in the first scroll then it start mix position randomly 
I DON'T KNOW WHY ?? PLEASE HELP

I Am Using Xamarin
and there is my code

```
public class SlidingTabsFragment : Fragment
    {
        private SlidingTabScrollView mSlidingTabScrollView;
        private ViewPager mViewPager;
        protected static View CurrentView;
        protected static int CurrentViewPosition;

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_sample, container, false);
        }

        public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            mSlidingTabScrollView = view.FindViewById<SlidingTabScrollView>(Resource.Id.sliding_tabs);
            mViewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
            mViewPager.Adapter = new SamplePagerAdapter();
            mViewPager.PageSelected += MViewPager_PageSelected;
            mViewPager.PageScrolled += MViewPager_PageScrolled;
            mSlidingTabScrollView.ViewPager = mViewPager;

        }

        private void MViewPager_PageScrolled(object sender, ViewPager.PageScrolledEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Position < mViewPager.ChildCount && e.Position>=0)
            {
                SamplePagerAdapter ad = (SamplePagerAdapter)mViewPager.Adapter;
                TextView txtTitle = mViewPager.GetChildAt(e.Position).FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.item_title);

                int pos = ad.GetItemPosition(CurrentView);
                txtTitle.Text = e.Position.ToString();
            }

        }

        private void MViewPager_PageSelected(object sender, ViewPager.PageSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Position < mViewPager.ChildCount && e.Position >= 0)
            {
                SamplePagerAdapter ad = (SamplePagerAdapter)mViewPager.Adapter;


                TextView txtTitle = mViewPager.GetChildAt(e.Position).FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.item_title);

                txtTitle.Text = e.Position.ToString();
            }
        }


        public class SamplePagerAdapter : PagerAdapter
        {
            List<string> items = new List<string>();
            public override void SetPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Java.Lang.Object obj)
            {
                CurrentView = (View)obj;
                CurrentViewPosition = position;
            }
            public SamplePagerAdapter() : base()
            {
                items.Add("Home");
                items.Add("Sell");
                items.Add("Rent");
            }

            public override int Count
            {
                get { return items.Count; }
            }

            public override bool IsViewFromObject(View view, Java.Lang.Object obj)
            {
                return view == obj;
            }

            public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
            {
                View view = LayoutInflater.From(container.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.pager_item, container, false);
                container.AddView(view);


                return view;
            }

            public string GetHeaderTitle (int position)
            {
                return items[position];
            }

            public override void DestroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Java.Lang.Object obj)
            {
                container.RemoveView((View)obj);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it , It was because I have to Set OffScreenLimit property